# booktabs-de from texlive-lang-german not installed in debian wheezy

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, booktabs, debian

I have debian wheezy with packaged texlive (TeX Live 2012/Debian) and want to use the package `booktabs-de` from the apt-package [texlive-lang-german](http://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/texlive-lang-german). The debian apt installation of that package ran fine.
I'm wondering, why it is not really installed (into the tds). Please have a look at those lines

```
apt-file show texlive-lang-german | grep  booktabs
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/booktabs-de/README-DE
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.dtx.gz
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.ins
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.pdf
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-lang-german/latex/booktabs-de/README-DE
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-lang-german/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.dtx.gz
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-lang-german/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.ins
texlive-lang-german: /usr/share/doc/texlive-lang-german/latex/booktabs-de/booktabs-de.pdf
```

meaning the package contains it - but it is not installed as the following lines show:

```
find / -name 'booktabs*.sty'
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
```

Okay, I can run the .ins-file and move the results - but shouldn't that be done already by the installer? Is this a debian bug? If, feel free to move this question into the right forum. Thanks.

Comment: presumably the debian packagers chose not to add the file(s).  what goes from tex live into debian is _their_ decision, nothing to do with the tex live team (or indeed to most of use readers of tex/sx)

Comment: Please ask the debian TeX maintainers; if you think it's a bug, report it.

Comment: Hi @MartinSchröder, okay - I'll file a bug tomorrow. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: As the Debian maintainer: Generally *everything* that is in TL from TUG goes into the Debian packages, unless there are other Debian packages that provide the same. In the later case there is a dependency from the original texlive-* package so that in any case all the files are installed. Nothing should be missing.

Comment: On the off-chance you want to read the German version of the manual, use `texdoc booktabs-de`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: booktabs-de is the *translation* of the booktabs manual. So there is no booktabs-de LaTeX package. Use the normal booktabs.sty (which is in texlive-latex-recommended).

Comment: Hi norbert, thanks for your solving lines: I misunderstood the package.

Comment: UUUuuuuuuuuuuups,
norbert - are you sure? Running MikTeX on windows results in
`("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs-de\booktabs-de.sty"
Package: booktabs-de 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables` thus there is a booktabs-de.sty-file.

Comment: And now - sorry - I can not edit the last comment: Those MikTeX-Files `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs-de\booktabs-de.sty"` and `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\booktabs\booktabs.sty"` are equal - only different within namings...